# Which Android library for twitter is easiest to work with?

Tags: android, twitter

There is

com.sugree.twitter, java me api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `Twitter4j`

Click on the following link to get source code

http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html

Answer (score 1):

You should go for Twitter4j OAuth

> OAuth is an open protocol which allows
>   the users to share their private
>   information and assets like photos,
>   videos etc. with another site without
>   sharing their credentials (username
>   and password) to the latter. Hence
>   making it very secure way of
>   transmission of data..

here is link for this...

1. http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/twitter4j-oauth-on-android.html